# Wrong number of cells in tableview in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

In my iPhone application I have a tableview.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 2;
}
```

but `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` calls only one time in ios 7. How can I resolve this issue?

```
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 158) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   switch (indexPath.row) 
   {
        case 0: return 98;       
        default: return 60;
    }
}
```

Comment: double check your delegate have been set

Comment: I have tableView.delegate = self; in didload method

Comment: Check ur numberofsectionsinTableview   method

Comment: could you show how your initializing your tableview?

Comment: I have update my question with initializing tableview code

Comment: What's the size of your cell (height) ?

Comment: what about `-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` ??

Comment: put a breakpoint before returning a cell in your method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. And check if your cell and its attributes are allocated or not.

Comment: my first cell is allocated and i can see it in ui

Comment: What about the second? if not, are you using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` with a correct identifier? it is necessary to allocate and initiate a cell if this last method returns nil.

Comment: the first cell return not null

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be one (ore more) of the following:

1. Datasource & delegate not properly set (not your case here)
2. `numberOfRowsInSection:` returns 1 (not your case here)
3. the table view shows only one cell on the screen (the table view frame is smaller or equal with the height of the cell + height of the header/footer)

Just in case, double check all of these and let us know the results.

Comment: the third one is not my case too i have checked it

Comment: Actually 3 is your problem, just increase the height of your table view at 300 (just a s example) and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Check you set `deletage` AND `datasource`

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.datasource = self;
```